# iOS Swift - Static Map View onClick action to launch Map App

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit

I have a static map view created on my main view. 
I have not found a detailed method on how to add the click event to this map image so I can then launch the default Apple Maps application.
Any pointers would be greatly received.
Thanks.

Comment: Add a Tap Gesture to handle the tap

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @nanjunda. I found this [link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/gesture-recognizer-using-swift) which has put be back on track.